# Cannot write to Folder mounted with SSHFS

Tags: ssh, sshfs, chmod

I just created a folder according to [SSHFS (Ubuntu Docs)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS)

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
sudo gpasswd -a jm fuse
sshfs -o idmap=user jm@example.com:/path/to/folder folder
```

Then I found that the folder is mounted, but I cannot write to it. The permissions seems fine

http://pastie.org/1969299

But I even tried with

```
chmod -R 777 ./folder
```

Still no go

UPDATE: It seems I can't write using NetBeans only. But it works with LeafPad for example

Comment: It would help if you posted a short transcript showing how you tried to write to the sshfs filesystem, along with the resulting error.

Answer (score 5):

Your update indicates that only certain applications are having trouble writing to the sshfs mount. You might have to enable one or more of the "workarounds" listed in the [sshfs man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs). I would start with the "truncate" and "rename" workarounds:

```
sshfs -o idmap=user -o workaround=truncate:rename jm@example.com:/path/to/folder folder
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear from your description what are the local and remote user, and what are the permissions of the files.

In any case, I would try to use the option `-o allow_other` on the `sshfs` command line.

Comment: local I am `jm` server I have both `jm` and something else

Answer (score -1):

You need to install [FUSE](http://ittyb.it/u79cbd2d1) and add yourself to the group.

```
sudo apt-get install fuse-utils
sudo modprobe fuse
sudo gpasswd -a $USER fuse
```

Restart your machine and attempt to mount the drive again.

I would recommend that you add a rule to your /etc/fstab file, much like this:

```
sshfs#user@host.com:/ /mnt/local-dir/ fuse comment=sshfs,noauto,users,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,reconnect,transform_symlinks,BatchMode=yes,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-blahblah 0 0
```

Then you can run `mount /mnt/local-dir` to mount the remote filesystem.

If you are unfamiliar with [public-key authentication](http://ittyb.it/ue4713e92), remove the ',IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-blahblah' and go look into public-key authentication :D

Comment: `sshfs` depends on `fuse-utils` and cannot work without. The user already has it, so your suggestion cannot solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is that he does not have FUSE configured correctly.  At one time, it was required to install FUSE. I have updated the answer to be more helpful. I am very confident that FUSE is indeed his problem.

Comment: In my experience, you cannot mount a FUSE filesystem at all unless FUSE is already configured. The fact that the OP has successfully mounted the filesystem indicates that this has been done already. The information on fstab and public-key auth, while useful, is not relevant to solving the OP's problem.